# Why does procedure affect on a loop?

Tags: for-loop, pascal, procedure

**Why does procedure effect on a loop?**

When I put a procedure `Line` in a `for`-loop, it makes it endless and I have only to close the console window and lose all unsaved data.

Here is the full code of my program and there are comments (at the end) that point at the problem:

```
uses crt;
var
n, i :integer;
a, b, h, x, res :real;


function func_1(y :real) : real;
  begin
    func_1:= (y*y*y*y) * (1 + sin(y) * sin(y));
  end;


function func_2(y :real) : real;
  begin
    func_2:= sin(y/2) / cos(y/2);
  end;


function func_3(y :real) :real;
  begin
    func_3:= sin(y) * cos(y);
  end;

procedure Line(sideSymbolLeft: char; usualSymbol: char;
               divideSymbol: char; sideSymbolRight: char);
  begin
    write(char(sideSymbolLeft));
    for i := 2 to 75 do
      begin
        write(char(usualSymbol));
        if ( (i mod 19) = 0 ) then
          write(char(divideSymbol));
      end;
    writeln(char(sideSymbolRight));
  end;


begin
  clrscr;

  a:= 0;
  b:= 2 * pi;
  n:= 7;
  h:= ( b - a ) / n;


  Line(char(201), char(205), char(205), char(187));
  writeln(char(186),'Functions of one variable':50,char(186):28);
  Line(char(204), char(205), char(203), char(185));
  writeln(char(186),'    Argument X    ',char(186),'  x^4*(1+sin^2(x)) ',
          char(186),'      tg(x/2)      ',char(186),'   sin(x)*cos(x)  ',char(186));

  for i:= 0 to n do (* calculating all Xs (arguments) *)
    begin
      x:= a + (i * h);
      write('   ');
      write(x:8:3);

      res:= func_1(x);
      write('              ');
      write(res:8:3);

      res:= func_2(x);
      write('   ');
      write(res:8:3);

      res:= func_3(x);
      write('         ');
      writeln(res:8:3);

      (* HERE IS THAT PROCEDURE *)
      (* When I put it here, the loop becomes endless *)
      (* and I have to close the console (and lose all unsaved data) *)
      Line(char(204), char(205), char(203), char(185));

    end;


  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Nothing is jumping out as an obvious issue, though I haven't touched Pascal in years. Have you tried stepping through the code? What is you comment out the body of `Line`, does it still get stuck? - I'm rusty here, should you have that semi colon at the end of the procedure definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same global loop counter variable `i` in two places at the same time (inside `Line` and in the main body loop that calls it). (This is one of the reasons that global variables are bad, BTW.)

```
// In Line()
for i := 2 to 75 do

// In calling code
for i:= 0 to n do (* calculating all Xs (arguments) *)
```

This means that every time the second loop runs and calls `Line()`, the counter gets reset (inside `Line`) to 2.

Add a local variable inside `Line` that handles the counter there instead:

```
procedure Line(sideSymbolLeft: char; usualSymbol: char;
               divideSymbol: char; sideSymbolRight: char);
var
  Ctr: Integer;
begin
  write(char(sideSymbolLeft));
  for Ctr := 2 to 75 do
  begin
    write(char(usualSymbol));
    if ( (Ctr mod 19) = 0 ) then
      write(char(divideSymbol));
  end;
  writeln(char(sideSymbolRight));
end;
```